# 16.04 second monitor does not work

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I always had problems with second monitor on my Ubuntu (it was not able to fall to sleep mode) but after upgrade it does not work, the scenario is very similar, it does not change mode to sleep, but now it cannot detect the second screen.
Both monitors are connected through HDMI cable.
Both ports and cables work perfectly of course I have checked every configuration.
Please find my pc config and  bellow:

- [pc config](http://www.morele.net/inventory/info/lFh3rO/)
- [video](http://sendvid.com/l9njkk0q)

I think the only solution for now is to downgrade the system, can you share any manual with me? Have anyone done this? I cannot google it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to boot using HDMI and it fixed everything!

inside BIOS I changed 'boot display' to HDMI

It may solve your problem